# Percona client installation failed in linux server with aarch64 architecture

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster, pmm-server

I am trying to install Percona client on two different Linux servers with the same ubuntu version (20.04.2 LTS), but with different architecture. The percona client got successfully installed in the server with x86_64(amd64) architecture but failing to install in the server with aarch64 architecture. I am facing the following error in the server with aarch64-

[image]

Steps followed to install the percona client

1. Download Percona Repo Package

`wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb`

2. Install Percona Repo Package

`sudo dpkg -i percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb`

3. Update apt-cache

`sudo apt-get update`

4. Install Percona Monitoring and Management Client

`sudo apt-get install pmm2-client`

I followed the installation steps given in the below link.

[https://www.percona.com/software/pmm/quickstart#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Install%20Client](https://www.percona.com/software/pmm/quickstart#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Install%20Client)

Please suggest a solution to install percona client in Ubuntu with aarch64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Percona does not currently support the `aarch64` architecture. You will not be able to install any Percona software for ARM-based processors. Please reach out to Percona on social media to voice your support for ARM as we base our roadmaps and support on user feedback.